# Centre all columns of an array

Tags: python, array, numpy

I have this working code tested over lots of np.arrays. It is a for-loop that walks through all the values of a np.array (x,y).

For each y-row, it finds the first x-column for which the value is different to zero. Afterward, it finds the last x-column for which value is different to 0.

Then all the columns between first x-column and last x-column are centred.

This is then repeated for all y-rows.
Example:

```
#Input :
array([[ 0.0,  0.149,  0.064, 0.736,  0.0],
       [ 0.0,  0.0,  0.258,   0.979,  0.618 ],
       [ 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,     0.786,  0.666],
       [ 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,     0.782,  0.954],

 #Output :
array([[ 0.0,  0.149, 0.064, 0.736, 0.0],
       [ 0.0,  0.258, 0.979, 0.618, 0.0],
       [ 0.0,  0.786, 0.666, 0.0,   0.0],
       [ 0.0,  0.782, 0.954, 0.0,   0.0],
```

Also:

- Not all the values between first and last columns are different than zero.

  ```
  for y in range(len(array)):

      begin = False
      inside = False
      end = False

      for x in range(len(array[0])):


          if (array[y][x] == 0) & (begin == True) & (end == False):
              boundary_two = ( x - 1 )
              inside = False
              end = True

          elif (array[y][x] != 0) & (inside == False):
              boundary_one = x
              begin = True
              inside = True

      y_position.append(y)
      m = np.split(array[y],[boundary_one,boundary_two])
      zeros = len(array[0])-len(m[1])
      array[y] = np.concatenate((np.zeros(zeros//2),m[1],np.zeros(int(np.ceil(zeros/2)))))
  ```

Furthermore, I added a variable(count) inside the function (which I erase for the upper code example, to simplify lecture) which count how many empty rows since last non empty rows. When count ==10, we break out of the loop. This is to save time. Once we have +/- 10 empty rows after the non-empty ones, it is sure all other y-rows will be empty as well.

Finally, I must save the value for the last y-row non-empty.

This is my script most time demanding calculation, so I was wondering if there is a way of to improve it, either by making it clearer and/or faster.

Thanks a lot, hope it is clear!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Does the code function correctly?  If not, it isn't ready for review (see [help/on-topic]) and the question may be deleted.  If you've tested it, I recommend that you [edit] to add a summary of the testing (ideally as reproducible unit-test code), and update the title to simply state *the task accomplished by the code*, which is the Code Review standard for titles (suggestion: "*Centre all columns of an array*").

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I've changed the title and added the fact that the code is working.

Comment: In your example, why is the second row rearranged so that 0.618 comes first?

Comment: It isn't suppose to come out like that, i corrected it. Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## review

### comparison

no need to compare against True or False. `(begin == True)` can be easier expressed as `begin` and `(end == False)` as `not end`. and comparison chaining is done with `and`, not `&`(bitwise and)

## iteration

In python, it is very seldomly needed to iterate over the indices. Instead of `for y in range(len(array)):` and `for x in range(len(array[0]))`, you can do

```
for row in array:
    ...
    for x, element in enumerate(row):
        if element == 0 and begin and not end:
```

## alternative solution

try to vectorise as much as possible. The easiest thing to do is count the zeroes in front and at the back:

```
def count_zeroes(array):
    return (array.cumsum(axis=1) == 0).sum(axis=1)

zeroes_front = count_zeroes(array)
```

and then the same for the reverse:

```
zeroes_back = count_zeroes(test_data[:,::-1])
```

The amount each row needs to roll is:

```
roll = (zeroes_front + zeroes_back) //2 - zeroes_front
```

> ```
> array([ 0, -1, -2, -2])
> ```

and then you apply this roll over each row:

```
np.array([np.roll(row, r) for row, r in zip(test_data, roll)])
```

> ```
> array([[0.   , 0.149, 0.064, 0.736, 0.   ],
>        [0.   , 0.258, 0.979, 0.618, 0.   ],
>        [0.   , 0.786, 0.666, 0.   , 0.   ],
>        [0.   , 0.782, 0.954, 0.   , 0.   ]])
> ```

in total:

```
def centre(array):
    zeroes_front = count_zeroes(array)
    zeroes_back = count_zeroes(array[:,::-1])
    roll = (zeroes_front + zeroes_back) //2 - zeroes_front
    return np.array([np.roll(row, r) for row, r in zip(array, roll)])
```

Comment: Wow, I can express how incredibly simple your solution is...Thanks a lot !!
I'm taking my time to process all the new functions i didn't knew about.

Comment: when used correctly, python can be very elegant